# What does the Boolean expression "this is T self" mean?

Tags: c#, generics

I just came across this code which I don't understand:

```
public class RunBuilder : IServiceBuilder
{
    public void Match<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : class, IServiceBuilder
     {
        if (callback == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));

            if (this is T self)
                callback(self);
        }
}
```

What does **`this is T self`** exaclty do? I couldn't find any link to it or what i should search for!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching

Comment: im aware of pattern matching. But i was not sure what the "self" does. Apparently i can change it to anything, since it's just the variable name used after casting?

Comment: Yes it's just a variable name, `if (this is T myVar) callback(myVar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so called [declaration pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns) which basically performs a  cast and in case of success assigns the value to `T self` variable which can be used inside the `if` block. You can see it with decompiler. For example [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE8dhyALIgLICGALgMYAWAPACoB8AFCBGI04lWQDZ8ARmSoBrAJTZc0gO40ApgCd5iBogBcyMFJxYY06QEsAZoha8BwsYgC8NxADsArgMn6DHijUUB7GY/l/AEFFAHMnAFt5BwoAORc+AFEADyp5AAcKQx8HFgcyKJ9jc34hEQlxAG5YHQMTMy9DAGdEZtVEJvk+YzcPDwsysRZO7qragF9YcaA==) decompiles it to something like:

```
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
public void Match<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : class
{
    // ...
    T self = this as T;
    if (self != null)
    {
        callback(self); 
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Type-testing operators and cast expressions - `is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#is-operator)
- [Pattern matching overview: Type tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#type-tests)

Comment: It has a null check, but it is not a null check alone.  You've neglected the work that `this as T` is doing.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's good enough to understand! it's casting and checking if the cast was successfull!

Comment: @S.JohnFagone: Yes, it produces the same result of combined `this is T` and `T self = (T)this`, but only does the type-checking work once.

Comment: @BenVoigt fixed. Misread code a bit.

Comment: @S.JohnFagone misread code a bit. Please see the update.